# libgdx box2d background image

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

I need to apply some textures to my libgdx game. Among them is background image of airhockey table. It is 800x480px. I load it like this:

```
backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/background.png"));
```

My box2d world have points per meter divider of 100.

I get what I need when I do this in render method:

```
debugRenderer.batch.begin();
debugRenderer.batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0);
debugRenderer.batch.end();
debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined); 
// camera with viewport 8.0x4.8 - 100 times smaller
// than actual window
```

The problem is that physical bodies start to move 100 times faster after that. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I was using VirtualBox and Android x86. It turned out that it have no hardware OpenGL support so when I applied textures rendering speed dropped to 2-3 FPS. Now I'm using emulator with x86 system image, KVM, and GPU acceleration so it feels like real device.
The problem was that physical world was updated score times faster than rendered.

Comment: I think you need to show some more code.  Specifically, code that sets up your camera.  And the code that updates/initializes the physical bodies.